# Core Data To-many relationship with Mac OSX 10.6 is not supported?

Tags: core-data, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

i'm try to study Core Data programming to develop Mac OSX application...
I've Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and in **XCode 4** when i try to check "To-Many Relationship" in my relationship properties i've got this error:

**error: Unsupported Feature: to-many relationship Category.snipplet option requires Mac OS X 10.7 or later**

So it's possible that 10.6 SDK doesn't support to-many relationship? Obviously i want to develop an application target for 10.6 and later.

My core data schema is very simple, i have two entity with a to-many ralationship...

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you try to use an ordered to-many relationship. But they are only supported on Mac OS 10.7++ and iOS 5++.

Remove the checkmark from `ordered` in the core data Data Model Inspector panel.
You then have to order the relationships yourself (e.g. by adding an order attribute to your entity).